# how to insert same record in one column but different row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, insert

how can I insert the same records in two columns but different row without duplicating the two columns in the same row ?

I have two tables

> structure table rek

- rek int (Primary Key)
- name varchar (10)
- address varchar (15)

> structure table cek

- cek int (Primary Key)
- rek int (Foreign Key)
- date date

table rek

```
rek   name   address
001   Jane   Alaska
002   Amel   Washington
003   John   Virginia
```

table cek (I would like my output to look like the table below.)

```
cek    rek   date
01     002   12-05-2015
01     003   12-05-2015
02     002   13-05-2015
03     001   12-05-2015
```

how can I insert in table cek if I want output like table cek? When I trying to insert the data as shown in the above table I can't. When I removed the primary key from cek, the data was duplicated.

Comment: by definition, `insert` creates a NEW record. if you want to "insert" data into two different records, only one of them can be new. the other one would have to be an `update`.

Comment: so, can't i get output like table cek ?

Comment: so you want to view the output like cek or rek ? you are taking rek from REK tables and Adding them to CEK table along with dates...IS that correct?

Comment: What do "trying to insert the data" and "the data was duplicated" mean? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: umm... dates doesn't matter after all :) but thank you all for trying to help me :) and sorry if my question is hard to understand (i'm bad at explaining)  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your second table cek remove primary key and Fk from both the columns.
and create composite primary key on column (cek,rek) in this way in your words you can record  in two columns but different row without duplicating the two columns in the same row ... 
or else the best thing to do is to create bridging table between these two columns

Comment: @Ritsu Something you changed might have solved your problem but you do not have to remove FKs to declare composite PKs. You should keep that FK. Your insert problems may have to to with FKs. But please edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring column cek as primary key, you are saying that each cek value is unique in the table. But from your desired output, that's not what you want. Maybe what you want is that (cek,rek) pairs or (cek,rek,date) triplets are unique. If so, declare such a (composite) primary key instead. But you haven't told us enough for us to know the primary key.

Comment: thanks~~ you're right for using composite key, but i've got stuck because of foreign key, but now it's solve :) thank you for helping me

Comment: What does "because of foreign key" mean?

Comment: at first, i use foreign key on table cek (field rek), so i can't make composite key, then i remove the foreign key on table cek, and now it works (sorry for bad explaining)

Comment: A FK declaration does not stop you from making a PK (composite or otherwise). It just forces all FK subrow values in the referencing table to already be in the referenced table. However a FK referencing subrow has to be a (super)key (PK or UNIQUE) in the referenced table even that table also has a smaller key. If you would show your DDL, DML, input, output and expected output per my comment on your question then we could actually see what is going on.